# Adding ngx-dropzone twice in a component to select different Images

Tags: typescript, dropzone, angular15

I want to add ngx-dropzone in my component so that it can select different images[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGGrW.png)

Here's my HTML code

```
type here<div class="statement">
    <ngx-dropzone class="drop" (change)="onSelect($event)">
    </ngx-dropzone>
    <ngx-dropzone-image-preview *ngFor="let f of files" [file]="f" [removable]="true" (removed)="onRemove(f)">
    </ngx-dropzone-image-preview>
  </div>
```

My TS code

`

```
 files: File[] = [];
  onSelect(event: any) {
    console.log(event);
    this.files.push(...event.addedFiles);
  }
  onRemove(event: any) {
    console.log(event);
    this.files.splice(this.files.indexOf(event), 1);
  }
```

I have tried changing the names of the methods and the parameters in them but no use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `multiple` on the `ngx-dropzone` to make it accept multiple images.

> This component has the following Input properties:
> [multiple]: Allow the selection of multiple files at once. Defaults to true.

You can find more in the [docs](https://github.com/peterfreeman/ngx-dropzone#ngx-dropzone-1)

```
<ngx-dropzone multiple (change)="onSelect($event)">
    <ngx-dropzone-label>Drop it, baby!</ngx-dropzone-label>
    <ngx-dropzone-preview *ngFor="let f of files" [removable]="true" (removed)="onRemove(f)">
        <ngx-dropzone-label>{{ f.name }} ({{ f.type }})</ngx-dropzone-label>
    </ngx-dropzone-preview>
</ngx-dropzone>
```

Comment: Thank you but I made it worked using if else statement.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).